# Transferring data from subscribe() to variable in Angular 6

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

In the below function, console.log(data) is returning my payload, but I am getting "undefined" in console.log(this.finalData). What is the best practice for storing the subscribed data to my this.finalData variable?

component.ts

```
getFavorites(){
  this.jobService.getFavoritesFromDB().subscribe((data) =>  { 
   console.log(data)
   this.finalData = data
  });
  console.log(this.finalData)

 }
```

service.ts

```
getFavoritesFromDB(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/post");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to place the console.log inside the **`subscribe`**, since the response from the api comes asynchronously

```
getFavorites(){
  this.jobService.getFavoritesFromDB().subscribe((data) =>  { 
   console.log(data)
   this.finalData = data;
   console.log(this.finalData)
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use this.finalData once the the subscribe has completed, take a look at the **complete** event that is fired once the subscription successfully completes.

Example

```
  getFavorites() {
    this.jobService.getFavoritesFromDB().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.finalData = data
      },
      error => {
        // handle error calling getFavoritesFromDB()
      },
      () => {
        // Note: If getFavoritesFromDB() has an error, the complete function will not get called

        // The call getFavoritesFromDB() was successful
        // Now you can use this.finalData
        console.log(this.finalData);
      });
  }
```

For more information on **Subscribe** (**onNext**, **onCompleted**, and **onError**) see the official ReactiveX documentation: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

Answer (score 1):

problem is your console.log statement runs even before you get the response (asynchronous).

The way you are storing the data to a variable is perfectly fine, you just need to move console statement inside subscribe.

Below is how it's executes

```
console.log("going to call method") --- (1)

getFavorites(){ --- (2)
  console.log("executing...") --- (3)
  this.jobService.getFavoritesFromDB().subscribe((data) =>  { 
   console.log("data inside subscribe", data) --- executes when response arrives --- (5)
   this.finalData = data
  });
  console.log("data outside subscribe", this.finalData); --- (4)
  ... and continues   
 }
```

**O/P:**

```
going to call method
executing...
data outside subscribe  // undefined or null (blank)
data inside subscribe "your data"
```